# create private external DTD through java

Tags: java, xml

how to create XML file with private external DTD specified in DOCTYPE like below through java program:

```
<!DOCTYPE MY1 SYSTEM "my1.dtd">
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the W3C DOM implementation that is part of the Oracle JRE then use a  DOMImplementation https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-102161490 and do e.g.

```
Document doc = domImplementation.createDocument(
  null,
  "MY1",
  domImplementation.createDocumentType("MY1", null, "my1.dtd")
);
```